# Get the diff between two 2-dimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-difference

I need to get difference between `$array1` & `$array2` based on `StudentId` column values.

```
 $array1 = array(
     array('StudentId' => 1),
     array('StudentId' => 2)
 );
 $array2 = array(
     array('StudentId' => 1)
);
```

The output should be:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [StudentId] => 2 ) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this as following,

```
$array1 = array( array( 'StudentId' => 1 ), array( 'StudentId' => 2 ) );
$array2 = array( array( 'StudentId' => 1 ));
foreach($array1 as $a=>$val){
     if(in_array($val,$array2)){
          unset($array1[$a]);
     }
}

var_dump(array_values($array1));
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$array1 = array( array( 'StudentId' => 1 ), array( 'StudentId' => 2 ) );
$array2 = array( array( 'StudentId' => 1 ));

var_dump(array_diff_key($array1, $array2));
```

Output:

`array(1) { [1]=> array(1) { ["StudentId"]=> int(2) } }`

Comment: `array_diff_key` check only the key and not the value. Since `$array1` has keys `[0], [1]` and `$array2` has keys `[0]` the result will always return the second key, regardless of its value.

Comment: @Gil Agreed, however, the OP did not ask to check values, but to get the difference between the two arrays.

Comment: this is why I didn't call it a wrong answer, only wanted to point out this issue :)

Comment: @Gil I also agree with you. I need the way to compare value.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

> array array_diff ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $... ] )
>
> Compares array1 against one or more other arrays and returns the
>   values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

Comment: I tried `array_diff()` but then A PHP Error was encountered called **Array to string conversion**

Comment: If you're trying to `echo` or `print` the result, you will encounter an error because the return value is an array.  Use `var_dump(array_diff($arr1, $arr2));`

Comment: I tried `var_dump(array_diff($arr1, $arr2));`. It is also encounted that error

Comment: Perhaps change `$array1 = array( array( 'StudentId' => 1 ), array( 'StudentId' => 2 ) );$array2 = array( array( 'StudentId' => 1 ));` to `$array1 = array('StudentId' => 1, 'StudentId2' => 2);$array2 = array('StudentId' => 1);`, if possible.

Comment: No It's not possible. :(